# How to access a dynamic module by a user application

Tags: linux, make, embedded

i created a simple dynamic module(.ko).How can a  user application  can  access driver  from  the kernel space.How to  get  the  major and minor  number  of    dynamically  loaded  module.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a lot of information in this question that would allow someone to answer it properly. I will make some assumptions and give a brief answer:

First, I'm assuming you're referring to Linux, and you've inserted the module in the kernel and checked that it is installed and running correctly. I'm also assuming that your driver creates a device node in the /dev directory.

All you'll need to do to get the major and minor numbers is to run `ls -l /dev/<yourdevnode>`. For example, for /dev/fuse:

```
$ ls -l /dev/fuse 
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 10, 229 Jan  3 09:08 /dev/fuse
```

Here, 10 and 229 are the major and minor numbers respectively.

Comment: Yes i'm referring to Linux.I created a dynamic  module inthe  location /home and  compiled the  module  using make. And  inserted   using  insmod.But   i  could not  find  the  device  node  in  /dev  location.How   to  create  a  device  file using  mknod? when   i  use  " ls -l "  in the  location  of  .ko i get " -rw-rw-r--   1 safedrive safedrive  3449 Jan  2 14:34 sample.ko"  .so  how can  i find  the  major  and minor number of the   module? .

Answer (score 0):

Are you a device driver like `hello world`?
If so, node is not created in the /dev directory.
You can also use the mknod command to create /dev/node.
But I do not know what your device driver does(you may not need a device node depending on the driver).
I do not have your driver source, so I guess.
Generally, the device driver uses the kernel function to create a device node.
I would like to recommend http://derekmolloy.ie/writing-a-linux-kernel-module-part-2-a-character-device/
In the above link, the `ebbchar_init()` function creates `/dev/ebbchar` through the `device_create()` function.
Of course, you will also find major and minor entries in the source.
Find out if your driver is using the above functions. And check if there is an error.